# How do I add this GUI code to this script?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I have been trying to make a virtual assistant (like Siri) and named it Jarvis (cause why not). I have been trying to make its GUI using Tkinter. The problem I am facing is that whenever I run the file, the GUI starts and not the main program. When I close the GUI, then the main program starts to run.
Here is the code I have written in the main file (`Main.py`):

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import pywhatkit
from pywikihow import WikiHow, search_wikihow
import wikipedia
import webbrowser as web
import os
from playsound import playsound
from pyautogui import click
from keyboard import press
from keyboard import write
from time import sleep
import datetime

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def takeCommand():
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 0.9
        audio = r.listen(source,0,5)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        speak("Could you repeat that sir?")
        print("Could you repeat that sir?")
        return "None"
    return query

def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        speak("Good Morning Sir")

    elif hour>=12 and hour<16:
        speak("Good Afternoon Sir")

    else:
        speak("Good Evening Sir")

    speak("Jarvis Mark 2 reporting. How may I help You?")

def GoogleSearch(term):
    query = term.replace("jarvis","")
    query = query.replace("what is","")
    query = query.replace("who is","")
    query = query.replace("how to","")
    query = query.replace("what do you mean by","")
    query = query.replace("what do we mean by","")

    Query = str(term)
    pywhatkit.search(Query)

    if 'how to' in Query:
        max_result = 1
        how_to_func = search_wikihow(query=Query,max_results=max_result)
        assert len(how_to_func) == 1
        how_to_func[0].print()
        speak(how_to_func[0].summary)

    else:
        search = wikipedia.summary(Query,2)
        speak(f": According To Google : {search}")

def YoutubeSearch(term):
    result = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + term
    web.open(result)

def DateConverter(Query):
    Date = Query.replace("and","-")
    Date = Date.replace("and","-")
    Date = Date.replace("and","-")
    Date = Date.replace("and","-")
    Date = Date.replace(" ","")

    return str(Date)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    speak("Status:Online")
    wishMe()

    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()

        if 'google search' in query:
            query = query.replace("google search","")
            query = query.replace("what is","")
            query = query.replace("jarvis","")
            speak("searching the web")
            GoogleSearch(query)

        elif 'youtube search' in query:
            query = query.replace("youtube search","")
            query = query.replace("jarvis","")
            speak("searching youtube")
            YoutubeSearch(query)
            speak("done sir")

        elif 'set alarm' in query:
            os.startfile('F:\Aryav files\J.A.R.V.I.S\J.A.R.V.I.S. Mark II\Jarvis GUI\Database\ExtraPro\Alarm.py')

        elif 'whatsapp message' in query:
            name = query.replace("whatsapp message","")
            name = name.replace("send","")
            name = name.replace("to","")
            name = name.replace("jarvis","")
            name = name.replace("a","")
            Name = str(name)
            speak(f"What is the message for {name} sir?")
            MSG = takeCommand()
            os.startfile("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\WhatsApp\\WhatsApp.exe")
            sleep(15)
            click(x=278, y=112)
            sleep(1)
            write(name)
            sleep(2)
            click(x=216, y=240)
            sleep(2)
            click(x=629, y=694)
            sleep(2)
            write(MSG)
            press('enter')

        elif 'call' in query:
            name = query.replace("call","")
            name = name.replace("jarvis","")
            Name = str(name)
            os.startfile("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\WhatsApp\\WhatsApp.exe")
            sleep(10)
            click(x=278, y=112)
            sleep(1)
            write(name)
            sleep(2)
            click(x=216, y=240)
            sleep(2)
            click(x=1214, y=73)

        elif 'video call' in query:
            name = query.replace("video call","")
            name = name.replace("jarvis","")
            Name = str(name)
            os.startfile("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\WhatsApp\\WhatsApp.exe")
            sleep(10)
            click(x=278, y=112)
            sleep(1)
            write(name)
            sleep(2)
            click(x=216, y=240)
            sleep(2)
            click(x=1150, y=54)

        elif 'space news' in query:
            speak("What is the date for news extraction sir?")

            Date = takeCommand()
            Date = Date.replace("and","-")
            Date = Date.replace("jarvis","")
            Date = Date.replace("tell","")
            Date = Date.replace("me","")
            Date = Date.replace("give","")
            Date = Date.replace("you","")
            Date = Date.replace("replace","")
            Date = Date.replace("and","-")
            Date = Date.replace("and","-")
            Date = Date.replace("and","-")
            Date = Date.replace(" ","")

            Value = DateConverter(Date)
            from Nasa import NasaNews
            NasaNews(Value)

        elif 'image of mars' in query:
            from Nasa import MarsImage
            MarsImage()

        elif 'track' in query:
            from Nasa import IssTracker
            IssTracker()

        elif 'near earth' in query:
            from Nasa import Astro
            speak("The starting date ?")
            start = input("Enter the starting date : ")
            speak("The end date ?")
            end = input("Enter the end date : ")
            Astro(start,end)

        elif 'online class' in query:
            from Features import OnlineClass
            OnlineClass()
            break

        elif 'directions' in query:
            from Features import GoogleMaps
            GoogleMaps()

        elif 'tuition' in query:
            from Features import tuition
            tuition()
            break

        elif 'open visual studio code' in query:
            speak("Opening visual studio code")
            os.startfile('F:\\VSCode\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe')
            speak("Done sir!")

        elif 'open chrome' in query:
            speak("Opening chrome")
            os.terminate('C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe')
            speak("Done sir!")

        elif 'open mark 3' in query:
            speak("Opening Jarvis Mark 3 and going offline to prevent input confusion for me")
            os.startfile('F:\\Aryav files\\J.A.R.V.I.S\\J.A.R.V.I.S. Mark III\\Jarvis.py')
            break

        else:
            from Database.Chatbot.ChatBot import Chatterbot

            reply = Chatterbot(query)
            speak(reply)

            if 'bye' in query:
                break
            elif 'exit' in query:
                break
            elif 'offline' in query:
                break
            elif 'rest' in query:
                break
            elif 'sleep' in query:
                break
```

Here is the Tkinter program I plan to add:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Jarvis")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

icon = PhotoImage(file='Jarvis.png')
window.iconphoto(True,icon)
window.config(background="#141414")

label = Label(window,image=icon,compound='center', bg= 'black')

label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Just tell me where do I need to copy paste that Tkinter code to what line number in the `Main.py` script or just make a new file that runs both together.

Comment: You can't just stick that tkinter code in some where in the `Main.py` script and have a usable GUI. GUIs are user-event-driven which means they run their own `mainloop()` which process each event as it occurs. You will need to design a GUI to run and control what your main script does and then implement it using various tkinter widgets (i.e. frames, labels, buttons, menus, text entries).

Comment: Why not to name your AI Jarvis: https://www.jarvis.ai/blog/jarvis-rebranded-to-jasper